# Why are my id and name attributes not always the same as my model property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

This problem only seems to happen with one Property from my model, *UserName*...

My model is

```
public class UserModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Firstname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public string ActiveAsText => Active ? "Active" : "Inactive";
}
```

here is how I have implemented in my page.

```
 <input asp-for="UserName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the username..."  required />
```

Logically, and according to the documentation, my id and name attributes should be my property name, so in this case UserName, but look at the id and name it is...

```
<input id="Username" name="Username" type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" placeholder="Enter the username..." required=""  value="" ng-model="pageModel.UserName" ng-class="isInputInvalid(form3E2F2153D9334BC08DFB3C68E16DF93D.UserName)">
```

Anyone have any ideas why?

I know I can just change the model name, blah blah blah, but it makes no sense why the issue only occurs with that model property but EmailAddress works correctly.

```
<input id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" type="email" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required form-control-danger" placeholder="Enter the email..." required=""  value="" ng-model="pageModel.EmailAddress" ng-class="isInputInvalid(form3E2F2153D9334BC08DFB3C68E16DF93D.EmailAddress)">
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this in 2.0. Could you setup an example project?

Answer (score 0):

Display attribute has no effect on `name` or `id` HTML attributes. It is for displaying the properties nicely in HTML pages. For example:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Your name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Lastname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public string ActiveAsText => Active ? "Active" : "Inactive";
}
```

---

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>@Model.FirstName</th>
    <th>@Model.Surname</th> 
    <th>@Model.EmailAddress</th>
    ...
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

---

It will be rendered like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Your name</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>E-mail address</th>
    ...
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```